# mahout random forest visualization

Tags: tree, visualization, mahout, random-forest

I made a model using BuildForest of random forest classifier in mahout.

I'm wondering how can I show a structure of trees in forests directly.

just I opened model at vi. but It doesn't help like bellow (few part of the file)

```
@^BA^TýËKKKK^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^B@<9a>xxxxxv^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^D@ç<
```

I googled it. I found [treeVisualizer](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout-0.7-cdh4.1.1/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/classifier/df/tools/TreeVisualizer.html) class

but it can't use directly I have no time for implementation using this API and debugging so.

**Is any ways to view tree or convert raw model file to can human recognize ?**

thanks for your help.

Comment: In the end, a tree representation of RF is not gonna help you to comprehend 500 trees with +500 nodes. If the trees are so simple you actually can, a simpler model could also have learned the same data structure. Consider visualizations with partial dependence plots or sensitivity analysis instead. Dunno about mahout, but these methods are wrap-able with any kinds of supervised models.

Comment: @SorenH.Welling I agree your opinion. It will be a complex model with big data. but I should verify to show the model to my client that how RF works. So the model should be just not a black box like a neural network.

Comment: I have been in a similar situation, were I advocated for a particular RF model predicting some chemical properties. First I showed the trees, and my receiver replied something like: "Oh that's a smart algorithm". Trees visualizations are very good to discuss the algorithm. After some minutes he asked again: "So what did your trained instance of the model actually learn in the case of our data?" ...... Both are valid questions:
How was the box made? What is inside the box?